# transition_post_status hook, works - but not if the post is new

Tags: php, posts, functions, hooks, post-status

I have no idea whats going wrong. My `transition_post_status` function works if the post is saved as a draft or another status first, then saved again as the 'transferring' custom post status, which it should fire on.

But if it is a new post, and saved immediately as the 'transferring' custom post status, then it will not work. But I do not think I have anything in my conditions to tell it not to fire on a new post.

```php
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'sending_from_interviewer_to_academic',99,3);
function sending_from_interviewer_to_academic($new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    
if (($post->post_type == 'research') && ($new_status == 'transferring') && ($old_status != 'publish') && ($old_status != 'started')) {...}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try checking if $old_status is set, or I think you can use "new" for $old_status to match posts that do not have an old status. (i.e. new posts). But you'd have to play around with that to get the right conditional.

Comment: Ah I did not think of that - thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately not, just tried testing without any $old_status conditions. However, since my question I managed to get it working by sending it to a different custom post type (I couldn't see any config differences between the two). However, it works when executed on the admin dashboard, but I use a form to usually submit posts - and it doesn't work when submitted before a save via the form builder. So now I think it is something on the form builder? Although the code works when saving first then submitting via the form builder...